# IE: simulate "print target" context menu command

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, printing, activex

IE have nice feature: if you right-click on some link you will see an option "print target". This option allows user to print almost anything via url (it could be link to doc file, excel or pdf - no metter if user have viewer for it). IE will download file and sent it to printer.

The question is: how do I simulate click on this menu item with JS or ActiveX? Or has IE some API for this behaviour?
All of your dirty hacks are welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's very unpopular and specific for IE function. One (and may be the only) way to "print target" - use ActiveX. I have no such script. If you have one, let me know :)